# Ruby Mysql - load .sql file and execute

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm trying to load a .sql file in a ruby script into a string and then execute it.

For some reason i'm getting a Syntax error, however if i copy and paste the statements directly into mysql it works just fine.

Here's how i do it:

```
text = File.read(src_sql_file)
new_text = text.DOINGSOMEGSUBSTUFF
@dbh.select_db(dbname)
sql = @dbh.prepare(new_text) 
sql.execute()
```

i've also tried this:

```
sql = @dbh.prepare(new_text)  do |sth|
  sth.execute()
end
```

and i always get:

```
Error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

'CREATE TABLE `the_logs` (
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PR' at line 5
```

where the sql for this looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `the_logs` (
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`timestamp` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
...
```

Any idea if i'm doing this wrong using prepare? i've also tried query.. didn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
T

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the entire statement and without knowing what DOINGSOMEGSUBSTUFF does. I would first try some trivial mysql statements that have a lower chance of a syntax error, to narrow it down.

Comment: Are you sure all your parenthesis are closed, and you have a `;` to close the statement? Can't see the entire SQL statement, so not exactly clear what it might be. Some GUI tools (assuming you're using the MySQL Query Browser, or some other GUI tool) often let you get away with not having the `;` at the end of the statement.

Comment: thanks. i left out the DOSOMESTUFF because it also doesn't work without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect whichever library you're using to talk to MySQL wants to handle one statement at a time and you're passing it several statements at once.

Try splitting the string on semicolons and executing each statement individually.